# How to create component and mount dynamically in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to create and mount components in a template dynamically. I attempted it but did not work. Below is the code. I have commented on the code on how I had wanted to achieve this.

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="12" class="d-flex flex-row">
        <v-btn color="success" @click="addField">Add Field</v-btn>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="12" id="container">
        mounts components here
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  methods: {
    addField() {
      //creates component
      let newComponent = Vue.component("some-component", {
        data() {
          return {
            name: "John"
          };
        },
        template: "<template><p>{{name}}</p></template>"
      });
      //insert component in template
      newComponent.$mount("#container");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to mount them in the data as opposed to the template? You can use [`v-for`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) to do this in the template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use `<component is="nameOfYourComponent"/>` to load components dynamically.
See here a very simple example in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bush-ymnlr?file=/src/App.vue)

And of course, the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't cleary understand the usecase tou want to achieve.

However, maybe you can get what you want using Slots (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) or Dynamic & Async Components (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)